# Why is there an image2wbmp but no image3wbmp, etc?

Tags: php, php-gd

PHP has a function called [image2wbmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image2wbmp.php), but there is not image3wbmp, image4wbmp, and so on. Why is that? Did the language designers think that image2wbmp would be enough?

Answer (score 0):

`image2wbmp` in written form means: "convert an image to wbmp". The 2 stands for "to" and is not related to a specific version if that was your thought.

Answer (score 0):

The main use of `image2wbmp` is to output or save a WBMP version of the given image.

It converts an image to wbmp..It returns  TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.